# HTML element to contain id or name from ko.observable using foreach

Tags: html, knockout.js

Below I have a for-each loop using *knockout.js*.

```
<div data-bind="foreach:Stuff">
    <div class="row">
            <span data-bind="text: $data.name"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to have the HTML Element with an `id` or `name` or something that reflects a unique value related to the $data.name value, as another method runs asynchronously, and needs to know which HTML element to update.

Ideally, it would look something like this, I guess:

```
<div data-bind="foreach:Stuff">
    <div class="row">
            <span id="data-bind='text: $data.name'" data-bind="text: $data.name"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: we cant have two `data-bind` for single element .

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but your second method shouldn't need to know about any id or name on the html-element as you should use the properties of the viewmodel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a knockout syntax that applies values during runtime to specified attributes:

```
<div data-bind="foreach:Stuff">
    <div class="row">
        <span data-bind="attr: { id: $data.name}"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its will assign dynamic id not value to element

Comment: @supercool That is exactly what I want, to give the element an ID based on the value of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this

```
<div data-bind="foreach:Stuff">
    <div class="row">
        <span data-bind="text: $data.name,attr:{id:$data.name}'"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here `name` is a observable i believe  when ever there is change in name in `stuff` it will automatically updates its value & `attr:{id}`just to give a dynamic `id` to element using available bindings .